# Merging JMeter Scripts

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, onlinebanking

Why JMeter is hanging, when trying to merge multiple Scripts in JMeter

I.M having 10 Scenarios, I'm trying to merge all under one Test plan. when I'M trying JMeter is hanging. it tooks more than a hour to do any actions.
JMeter heap size min-4gb ,max-5gb
I've tried in multiple machines same issue is happening.
Is there any solution please help me.
Any alternative to test multiple Sceanrios(10)

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file, normally it should contain the failure reason. If the reason is not there try [increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)
2. Take [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and inspect what exactly threads are doing
3. JMeter .jmx scripts are normal XML files, you can use your favourite text/XML editor and merge the scripts manually without using JMeter GUI
4. You can keep separate .jmx scripts and reference them using [Include Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri
how to merge the scripts manually with text/xml editor?